# I am using conditional statements to hide and show items in formIO. How can I get this to work with surveys?

Tags: javascript, formio

For example [Survey](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpwLs.png)

How do I get a text field (API name: textName) to appear using the advanced conditional logic? I presume I will need something like this in the text field advanced conditions;

show = (survey.question = starter) && (survey.value = good)

Any help on how I can write this would be amazing! Thanks

P.S Very much new to coding/formIO!

I have tried using the values assigned to each question and value.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.